# Can I cast Shield against an attack that hits me during a Time Stop?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, time, reactions

Suppose an enemy casts *Time Stop* and then makes an attack against me, rolling a 20 to hit against my 16 AC. Normally, I could cast *Shield* to cause this attack to miss. And of course, this attack also ends the *Time Stop*. So, does time start flowing "soon enough" for me to cast *Shield* against the attack that ends the *Time Stop* spell?

Comment: Though I did close this question, I could certainly see the argument made that the linked question never mentions the *shield* spell which is an exceptional enough spell to warrant its own question (after all, we have a **lot** of questions about *shield*)

Comment: @Medix2 Yeah, it's a bit ambiguous. Unfortunately the accepted answer kind of glosses over the details of the interaction between *Time Stop* and *Shield*.

Answer (score -1):

### Yes, you can cast *Shield*

*Time Stop* says:

> This spell ends if one of the actions you use during this period, or any effects that you create during this period, affects a creature other than you or an object being worn or carried by someone other than you.

As soon as the caster Attacks or creates some effect that affects a creature other than itself, the spell ends. Once the spell has ended, you can act normally, allowing you to cast *Shield* with your reaction, turning a potential hit into a miss.

Comment: If the attack misses, how does it affect you?

Comment: @MarkWells It affects you by making you a target. Whether or not you were successfully hit is irrelevant, as long as you were targeted.